# rosjava CallerID in MessageListener

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple way to get a publisher's callerID within a Subscriber/Message Listener in rosjava? I see that it gets stored in the publisher while in TcpServerHandshakeHandler.java:handleSubscriberHandshake() but do not see the subscriber having access to this.

Thanks,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37238/rosjava-callerid-in-messagelistener/) by [stevefturner](https://answers.ros.org/users/792/stevefturner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not currently supported. Please file a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0